# Does TFS has releases tab like we have at GitHub Releases

Tags: github, tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, tfsbuild

I am looking for hosting .exe files in Azure Devops. It seems to don't have feature similar to how we host executable or build files in GitHub for other people to download. Do we have such kind of feature to host the executables and have the latest commit tagged?

Answer (score 0):

You can try publishing the executable or build files as Build Artifacts in Azure devops build pipeline.

You can create a pipeline in azure devops and using [Publish build artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops) task to store the executable or build files in azure pipeline

See example [here](https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/azuredevops/continuousintegration/) to create a classic azure pipeline. See [Here](https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/azuredevops/yaml/#task-3-adding-a-yaml-build-definition) for yaml pipeline example.

When you run the pipeline. You will see the commit hash and the files uploaded in the highlighted field of the build summary page shown in below screenshot. And you download the files from there.

[image: Publish to azure pipeline]

You can retain this artifacts by Clicking `retain` in the pipeline run. See below

[image: retain]

You can also change the retention policy for your pipeline. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/policies/retention?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) for more information.

Go the Project settings page-->Settings under Pipeline. See below:

[image: retention]